# ¿Cómo corregir el error Process exited with code 3221226505?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, microsoft, wsl

He intentado Este enlace que les comparto y no se si lo modifique bien [(Posible Solucion pero a mi no me vale)](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7611)

El problema comienza al iniciar mi terminal de windows con ubuntu. Se demora unos 3 a 5 minutos en cargar la terminal y sale

> [Process exited with code 3221226505].

Tambien yo descarge mi ubuntu y terminal de la store por eso tal vez sea el problema, pero bueno sea lo que sea debe haber solucion por que paso de la nada y en las demas terminales como CMP no se ejecuta ningun comando de wsl y aparte de eso se demora mucho.
Les dejo un pantallazo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui tambien les dejo mi configuracion que recomiendan en el enlace que les comparti y si alguien sabe como solucionarlo y por que sucedio eso les agradeceria.Este problema parece ser uno nuevo por lo que veo que no hay mucha informacion. Con todo muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Miren gente si alguien sabe tambien le pasa esto a ubuntu voy a buscar informacion de lo que me sale pero si alguin por aqui sabe les agradecere les dejo una imagen de lo que pasa con el.La verdad soy nuevo en esto y me da un dolor de cabeza esto pero poco a poco voy asiendo cosas que me parece que ya mismo encuentro la solucion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando la encuentre va a estar en los comentarios de momento les agradesco por la ayuda y no duden en dejar su comentario si saben que es,!Gracias¡.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Este Windows sobre el que corres el contenedor, es tu máquina local, un servidor o qué es?

Comment: Hola, Gracias.Si es mi maquina local.

Answer (score 1):

Señores, para la gente que tenga el mismo problema, acabo de areglarlo.
Verán primero actualicen su sistema windows y reinicien (Esto viene de esta publicacion: [Información de ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142359/error-0x80080005-server-execution-failed-while-installing-ubuntu-on-windows)).

Despues abran la terminal y el problema cambia (sale otro) les dejo el enlace : [Nuevo error](https://github-com.translate.goog/microsoft/WSL/issues/5092?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=es&_x_tr_hl=es-419&_x_tr_pto=sc) y al final de esto su problema con la terminal se habrá solucionado. Bueno, eso espero, de momento a mi me sirvió, espero les sirva a ustedes también.

les dejo la imagen de mi terminal areglada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué bueno! Podrías hacer aún más poderosa la respuesta añadiendo EN la respuesta los detalles clave de lo que dice el segundo enlace? QUé comando correr o qué hacer con el segundo error. Recuerda también que en unas horas puedes incluso marcarla como respuesta aceptada para que otros que busquen el mismo problema sepan que ya tiene respuesta aceptada.